# Compare function in priority_queue/stl

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

```
 bool operator() (const pair<int,string>& a,const pair<int,string>& b){
        if(a.first!=b.first)
            return a.first>b.first;
        else
            return a.second < b.second;
    }
```

i have been doing heap problems, found out about this comparator function, here its comparing frequency of 2 words, but im not getting how exactly does it work and can't find any appropriate explanation of it. Could someone please explain it in a simple way? Thank you.

Comment: What is exactly unclear?

Comment: Recommendation: rephrase the question. State what you think is going on, why, and ask, "Am I right?" If you're right, cool beans. You didn't need us. If you're wrong, we can show you where your reasoning went awry, and that is far more useful going forward than just getting a description from one of us.

Comment: Plus often showing your work is the only thing separating your question from the horde of "Do my homework for me, please." non-questions flooding Stack Overflow daily.

Comment: Alright, my bad if i was unclear, what i cannot understand is that suppose i have numbers [1,1,2,1,2,3,3,4] , i count their frequency, make a pair, insert them into a max heap sorted by highest frequency (as min heap would do it itself), and when 2 numbers with similar frequency comes, the smaller numbers should come before. If i use greater<int> for min heap it wont work but this comparator is somehow working correctly for the given condition and im not really getting how exactly is it working

Comment: into a min heap*

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function sorts on the `int`s first in descending order. If two compared `int`s are the same, it'll do a lexicographical comparison of the `string`s and sort on those in ascending order.

Example, given a container with this content:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> vec{
    {1, "F"}, {2, "E"}, {3, "D"}, {4, "C"}, {5, "B"}, {6, "A"},
    {1, "A"}, {2, "B"}, {3, "C"}, {4, "D"}, {5, "E"}, {6, "F"},
};
```

Using a standard `std::sort` with your comparison function would produce this order:

```
6 A
6 F
5 B
5 E
4 C
4 D
3 C
3 D
2 B
2 E
1 A
1 F
```

For a [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) the extraction order will be the reverse since it puts the *largest* value on top and your comparison function says that a smaller number has higher priority than a larger number.

[Demo with debug prints](https://godbolt.org/z/5cfvc1dE5)

Note that I used [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) in the demo. It is often preferred when creating comparison functions that are required to do *strict weak ordering* because it makes it a lot easier to avoid making mistakes. It does the same as your original though:

```cpp
bool operator()(const std::pair<int, std::string>& a,
                const std::pair<int, std::string>& b) 
{
    return std::tie(b.first, a.second) < std::tie(a.first, b.second);
}
```

Comment: But how would the parameter be passing into the function? as i would just make min heap like priority_queue<int,vector<int>,comparator>, how will it call that function i mean when it pushes the first element how would it compare it (idk it might be dumb but its really confusing me)

Comment: @ArhamNaeem The function or class using `comparator` calls the comparison function with two of the objects at a time to figure out their relative order. I've added debug prints to the demo so you can see it in action.

Comment: Ok thanks for that, so can i say that like when the result is false, like i have [1,2,2], 1 is inserted into the min heap now when 2 will be inserted comparator will be called and it will check if(1>2), as false will be return, this 2 will be keep getting compared with the upcoming inputs until it satifies the condition?? it my thinking correct?

Comment: @ArhamNaeem When the result is `false` then either `a == b` or `a > b` (in the comparison function). When the result is `true`, then `a < b` - which for a `priority_queue` means that `a` is put after `b` and will be extracted after `b`. In which order the actual comparisons are done depends on the algorithm used. The complexity requirements for `std::make_heap`  used for the constructor in my demo is `3*std::distance(first, last)` but how it achieves that is implementation defined.